# Root access to files

Tags: .htaccess

I want to know how can i restrict access to my file on my root directory using .htaccess files on my root directory. I have the following code but it is not working.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: What file are you actually trying to restrict access to?

Comment: i am using wordpress and i want to restrict access to all the wordpress folders like wp-content and wp-includes like that..!!

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood you correctly, you want to block access to your wordpress files using `.htaccess`. To do this you can use:

```
<FilesMatch (wp-config|wp-admin|wp-content)\.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

Or if you're using Apache 2.4:

```
<FilesMatch (wp-config|wp-admin|wp-content)\.php>
Require all denied
</files>
```

You then just need to put in the specific files that you want to restrict access to. I've just included three of the important ones as an example. Hope this helps.

Comment: Well I will try this one and let you know if it work's :) ...!!

Comment: Did you have any luck @PranaySute